# Fastest way to transfer files between two adjacent computers

Tags: networking, file-upload, file-io, ftp, file-transfer

I have two adjacent computers, both running a recent version of Ubuntu. Both computers have:

- Multiple USB 2.0 ports
- RJ-45 connection
- 5400RPM hard drive
- Express Card card slot
- PCMCIA Type II

I want to transfer as much data as possible in a set period of time.

1. What is the fastest *physical* medium to transfer data between the two computers without swapping hard drives?
2. What is the fastest protocol (not necessarily TCP/IP based) for transferring high-entropy data? If it is TCP/IP, what needs to be tweaked for optimal performance?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, RJ-45 is not a medium, but just a connector type. So your ethernet connection could be anything between 10BASE-T (10 Mbit) and 10GBASE-T (10 Gbit). Using ethernet the link speed is defined by the lowest common speed grade supported by both peers.

The **USB Hi-Speed** mode is specified for 480 Mbit/s (60 MByte/s), but the typical maximum speed is somewhere near (**40 MByte/s**) due to the protocol overhead. This speed is only for direct USB host to client connections, but you have 2 USB hosts and so you need some kind of device in the middle to handle the client parts. I guess that will also lower the achievable data rate.

With **ethernet** you have a simple plug 'n play technology with a well known (socket) API. The transfer speed depends on the link type:

Max. TCP/IP data transfer rates (taken from [here](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/index.php/LAN_Ethernet_Maximum_Rates,_Generation,_Capturing_&_Monitoring)):

- Fast Ethernet (100Mbit): **11.7 MByte/s**
- Gigabit Ethernet (1000Mbit): **117.6 MByte/s**

Answer (score 1):

The USB 2.0 specification results in a 480 Mbit/s rate, which is 60 MB/s.

Ethernet depends on the network cards (NIC) used and to a lesser degree the wiring used. If both NICs are 1Gbit/s they will both auto-negotiate to 1 Gbit/s translating to 125 MB/s. If one or both NICs only support 100 Mbit/s then they will auto-negotiate to 100 Mbit/s and your speed will be 12.5 MBytes/s.

Wireless is also an option with 802.11n supporting up to 600 Mb/s (75 MB/s) - faster than USB 2.0.

USB 3.0 is the latest USB spec supporting up to 5 Gb/s (625 MB/s).

Ofcourse actual throughput will differ and depend on many other factors, such as wiring, interference, latency, etc.

TCP vs. UDP protocol depends on the type of connection you need and your application's capacity to deal with dropped packets, etc. TCP has a higher initial cost for building up the initial connection, but the transmission is reliable and for long running transactions may turn out to be the fastest. UDP is cheaper to create connections, but you may have dropped packets.

Maximum Transmission Unit (MTU) is a parameter than can have a significant affect on an IP based network. Picking the right MTU depends on several factors. The Internet has numerous articles on this.

Other tweaks are the basics like closing known chatty apps, netbios service if your on windows, etc (lots of hits on google for speeding up tcp).